# Jsonify for django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm using jsonify function to return in Flask:

```
 return jsonify(results = results_arr)
```

and I'm getting output like this:

```
{"results":[{"image":"103901.jpg","score":"2.51322851309"},{"image":"103401.jpg","score":"5.93861453397"}]}
```

I tried to do this in django by:

```
return json.dumps(results = results_arr)
```

But it doesn't work like on jsonify on Flask, can someone help me with this?

Comment: In Flask `return jsonify(...)` returns an HTTP response but `return json.dumps(...)` does not do the same. You need to use `return JsonResponse({'results': results_arr})`

Comment: @ettanany Thank you, it solved my problem!